# Accessing a 2D array defined in a typedef struct in the main function. Code is in C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, typedef

```
typedef struct DT {
   int ID;                  /* Class ID of this training pattern */
   int VecDim;              /* Vector dimension in Mat */
   int VecNum;              /* Number of vectors in Mat */
   float **Mat;             /* Vector sequence */
   struct DT *Next;
} DType;
```

A 2D array is defined in a `typedef struct`. I want to access it in the main function, with the dimensions of [10000][64]. I need 8 such matrices where each matrix reads 64 bytes of data from a data array. The operation is such that the first 64 bytes of the data array are filled in the first row of the first matrix, the next 64 in the first row of second matrix and so on. When all the 8 matrices have their first row filled up then it will start filling the second row of each matrix. 
Here `Mat` is a 2D array which I have to access it in the main function. Do I need to assign separate memory for each matrix which is been created?

Comment: including what you have tried in your `main()` function in your question would help

Comment: As such I have not yet tried till now, but I needed some help in terms of syntax to allocate dynamic memory to each matrix that I will be creating and then filling the data accordingly in each matrix.

Comment: I don't see any 2D arrays in your structure definition (which might look more like `float Mat[N][M]`). All I see is a pointer to pointer to float (`float **`), which might or might not be being used "like" a 2D array by some definition, but a simple `float *` could also be used "like" a 2D array. The code (not just a structure definition) is where that sort of thing is determined...

Comment: If you have 3 dimensions (#of arrays, rows, and columns), why two levels of indirection?  It'd make more sense to use either a `void *` and convert it to an appropriate pointer to 2D arrays (eg. `float (*)[8][64/sizeof(float)]`) when needed, or a `float ***`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon, and also the page about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]).  We don't usually write code from scratch, but we'll help sort out problems with the code you have got.  Your explanation of what you need to do is not clear — you've got 10,000 rows in each matrix, with 64 floats in each row.  How do you fill those floats from 64 bytes of data?  How do you fill 10,000 rows from the 64 bytes?

Comment: thank you for the suggestions I will start writing my own code first and will later ask questions. As far as the question is concerned I have got a float array of some size and I need to put those first 64 elements of that array in the first matrix and the next 64 in another and so on.

Comment: Is `DType` a linked list node?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to assign separate memory for each matrix which is been created?

Yes, if you do not assign `Mat` a value, it is considered a "dangling pointer," and attempting to access it will cause undefined behavior. You also must assign each matrix its own block of memory, or else they will all point to the same matrix. See the example below (assuming that `dt` is a linked list):

```
DType *dt = ...;
while(dt)
{
    dt->Mat = malloc(10000 * 64 * sizeof(float));
    dt = dt->Next;
}
```